# Second order linear ODE with variable coefficients

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Consider the second-order linear differential equation $u'' + p(x)u' + q(x)u = 0$ where $p$ and $q$ are continuous on the entire $\mathbb{R}$. Suppose that $q(x) < 0 $ everywhere. Show that if $u$ is not identically $0$ then $u$ can have at most one zero on $\mathbb{R}$.

Any suggestions on how to go about this? Anything will be deeply appreciated!

Comment: There seems to be an error in your question: Take $p(x) = 0$, $q(x) = -1$, then a solution of your ODE is given by $u(x) = x^2-1$, which has two zeros at $\{-1,1\}$.

Btw: your ODE is not "homogeneous".

Comment: I think you want to say $u'' + p(x)u' + q(x) u= 0$.

Comment: Yes! I will amend it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suggestion for a proof by contradiction:

- Take $x_0,x_1$ such that $u(x_0) = u(x_1) = 0$ and $u|_{(x_0,x_1)} \ne 0$. Assume wlog. that there is $x \in (x_0,x_1)$ with $u(x) > 0$.
- Take $x \in \mathrm{argmax}_{[x_0,x_1]} u$. By optimality, we have $u'(x) = 0$ and $u''(x) \le 0$. This contradicts the ODE.

Comment: How do you take a interval $(x_0,x_1)$ with $u\ne 0?$

Comment: One is supposing, for the purposes of contradiction, that $u$ has two roots. Since this is the case, the interval between the roots satisfies that $u(x) \neq 0$, since we are assuming $u$ has only two roots.

Comment: what is $argmax_[x_{0},x_{1}]u$ means?